# Nginx Bad Gateway with Django Social Auth and uwsgi

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, django-socialauth

My site is running correctly locally (using the built in runserver), but when running with nginx and uwsgi, I'm getting a Bad Gateway (502) during the [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) redirect.

The relevant nginx error_log:

`IPREMOVED - - [11/Oct/2012:12:10:18 +1100] "GET /complete/google/? ..snip .. HTTP/1.1" 502 574 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.26 Safari/537.11"`

The uwsgi log:

`invalid request block size: 4204 (max 4096)...skip
Thu Oct 11 12:16:46 2012 - error parsing request`

Refreshing the Bad Gateway response redirects and logs in correctly. This happens every single time. The nginx and uwsgi logs here have different timing as they were separate requests. The logs are consistent.

This is the first time deploying django to nginx for me, so I'm at a loss as to where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried increasing the size of the uwsgi buffer:

```
-b 32768
```

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.wsgi.uwsgi.general/1171

Comment: Yup, that did it. Banging my head against a wall for an hour or so. Thanks!